# How to seed data to a many-to-many link table in Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, database-migration

I have these two tables:

```
public class Resource  
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? NumberA { get; set; }
    public string? NumberB { get; set; }
    public ICollection<System> Systems { get; set; }
}

public class System
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? Code { get; set; }
    public string? Category { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Resource> Resources { get; set; }
}
```

Using EF Core creating migrations to the database, this creates a table called `ResourceSystem` with columns `ResourcesId`, `SystemsId`

Using the `DbContext` `modelBuilder.Entity<>().HasData()`, I can seed data to `Resource` and `System` tables. But in Visual Studio, I can not seed data to the "link table" `ResourceSystem` as it does not exists and I get the following error:

> [The type or namespace name 'type/namespace' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0246?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(CS0246))

How do I seed data to such a many-to-many link table created by EF Core?

Update (v2):

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ResourceSystem>()UsingEntity(j => j
.HasData(new[]
    {
        new { Resource.Id = 1, SystemId = 17 },
        new { Resource.Id = 2, SystemId = 7 }
    }
));
```

Comment: @Gert Arnold Where do i put the extension method? I put an update to the post, would it be like this?

Comment: You may not require the `ResourceSystem` class if you use EF conventions. As mentioned in the answer shared in comments:

`builder.Entity<System>.HasMany(s => s.Resource).WithMany(d => d.System)
            .UsingEntity(x =>
                 x.ToTable("ResourceSystem") //can omit using convention
                   .HasData(new { ResourceId = 1, SystemId = 7 })
            );`

Comment: shouldn't it be `new ResourceSystem{...}`

Comment: @Canica Thanks, was helpful for me. For me the linked suggested solution contained faulty syntax. For adding multiple entities i ended up with: .HasData(new[] {
    new { ResourceId = 1, SystemId = 7 },     new { ResourceId = 2, SystemId = 7 }, ....));. Note the 'new' keyword for each new entity. As someone suggested i had to use my 'intelligence' to identify the faulty syntax in the other post.